# How can I setState in not class component

Tags: react-native

I'm setting up a new application. I use [react-native-search-filter](https://github.com/mjsolidarios/react-native-search-filter) for filtering my list.

I have more than one Card Type. one of them Search bar component.

I need to

Card_10.js (Search Bar)

```
const Card_10 = (props) => {
  const {textStyle, cardStyle} = styles;


  return (
      <View style={cardStyle}>
        <Item style={{backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',marginTop:10,marginLeft:5,marginBottom:20,marginRight:5, borderRadius:10, height:40}}>
          <Icon style={{marginLeft:10, color:'#8e8d92'}} name="ios-search"/>
          <SearchInput
            style={styles.searchInput}
            onChangeText={(term) => {
              props.func(term) }}
            placeholder="Type a message to search"
          />
        </Item>
      </View>
  );
};
```

and my list Component is:
Card_8.js

```
const Card_8 = ({onPress, children, headers, bodylist, cardid}) => {
  const data = bodylist;
  this.state = {
    searchTerm: ''
  }
  function tiklandi(prop, itemid, cardid) {
    if (prop) {
      Actions.carddetail({itemid: itemid, cardid: cardid});
    } else {
      null
    }
  }
  function handleClick( name ){
    this.setState({searchTerm : name});
  }
  const filteredEmails = emails.filter(createFilter(this.state.searchTerm, KEYS_TO_FILTERS))

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onPress={onPress}>

      <Card_10 func={handleClick.bind(this)} />
      <Card style={{height: 40, marginTop: 0, marginBottom: 5}}>
        <CardItem>
          <Left>
            <Text style={[styles.itemleft, styles.baslik]}>{headers[0]}</Text>
          </Left>
          <Right>
            <Text style={[styles.itemright, styles.baslik]}>{headers[1]}</Text>
          </Right>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
      <FlatList
        data={filteredEmails}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) =>
          <Card style={{height: 40, marginTop: 0, marginBottom: 0}}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => tiklandi(item.IsClickable, item.ItemId, cardid)}>
              <CardItem style={{height: 40}}>
                <Left>
                  <Title style={styles.itemleft}>{item.ItemDatas[0]}</Title>
                </Left>
                <Right>
                  <Title style={styles.itemright}>{item.ItemDatas[1]}</Title>
                </Right>
              </CardItem>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </Card>}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

As you see I use Const type for my component. How can I do setState in Card_8.js on

```
function handleClick( name ){
    this.setState({searchTerm : name});
}
```

Comment: Only class components can have state. You would either have to convert it to a class component **or** handle the state in the parent component and pass the values via props.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Whatever components that are in the format

```
const abc = () => {
  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

are stateless components. Like the word, they don't have a state so you couldn't change the component.

I suggest you use PureComponent with state which is better than stateless components. They provide you the use of state as well as give you performance boost.

```
class abc extends PureComponent {
  state = {}

  someMethod = () => {
    this.setState({
      name1: value1,
    });

  }
}
```

Note. Always prefer `PureComponent` over `Stateless components`.

**Also for stateless components you can only manipulate state from parent component and pass it has props here.**

Comment: I know but my old work friend build with this method. I can not transform all component :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

function handleClick(name) {
  setSearchTerm(name);
}

const filteredEmails = emails.filter(createFilter(searchTerm, KEYS_TO_FILTERS))
```

Comment: Hooks will not be in `react-native` until version `0.59.0` https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.59.0-rc.1

Answer (score 1):

```
<Card_10 func={(name) => this.setstate({searchTerm: name})} />
```

///

```
const Card_10 = (props) => {
  const {textStyle, cardStyle} = styles;


  return (
      <View style={cardStyle}>
        <Item style={{backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',marginTop:10,marginLeft:5,marginBottom:20,marginRight:5, borderRadius:10, height:40}}>
          <Icon style={{marginLeft:10, color:'#8e8d92'}} name="ios-search"/>
          <SearchInput
            style={styles.searchInput}
            onChangeText={(term) => 
              props.func(term) }
            placeholder="Type a message to search"
          />
        </Item>
      </View>
  );
};
```